# google_visualr Image Bar chart labels are not in place

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I am using google_visualr gem. The GoogleVisualr::Interactive::ColumnChart generating correct chart but in GoogleVisualr::Image::BarChart labels are not on the right place in image.  See below scrrenshots.

GoogleVisualr::Interactive::ColumnChart

[image]

GoogleVisualr::Image::BarChar

[image]

model.rb

> data_table = GoogleVisualr::DataTable.new
>   data_table.new_column('string', x_axis)
>   data_table.new_column('number', y_axis)
>
> opts = {fontName: 'Open Sans', width: 400, height:
>   (data_for_chart.count > 6) ? 300 : 250, title: chart_name, color:
>   IM_IMAGE_BAR_CHART_COLOR, :legend => 'none', role: 'annotation'}
>
> data_table.add_rows(data_for_chart) chart =
>   GoogleVisualr::Image::BarChart.new(data_table, opts)

Any suggestion that how can i render chart with my html data? where i am going wrong?

I am using `rails 3` and `'google_visualr', '>= 2.1'`